# Passing String from one class to another in Android

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to transfer a String value from one class to another class in same package. The second class is called `using intent` in `onclick of a menu item`. I used the code

```
Intent i = new Intent(TouristGuideActivity.this, PointOfInterest.class);
i.putExtra("videoId", videoId);
startActivity(i);
```

in first class and then in second class,

```
String address=getIntent().getExtras().getString("videoId");`
```

But when I click on the menu item, I get a force close. If I remove that put Extra part, it works ine. But in that case I can't send the string. Please help!

Comment: You should have shown LogCat Error too..It might be possible error because videoId is null or something..put Log to Print videoId and check.

Comment: String address= getIntent().getStringExtra("videoId") also doesn't work. :-(

Comment: @Frankenstein In first class, if we print videod, it shows the value. Also I can use this value successfully in first class.

Comment: LogCat:- 12-15 12:46:17.022: W/KeyCharacterMap(2076): Can't open keycharmap file
12-15 12:46:17.032: W/KeyCharacterMap(2076): Error loading keycharmap file '/system/usr/keychars/synaptics.kcm.bin'. hw.keyboards.65541.devname='synaptics'
12-15 12:46:17.032: W/KeyCharacterMap(2076): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
12-15 12:46:18.162: W/dalvikvm(2076): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40028890)
12-15 12:46:18.172: E/AndroidRuntime(2076): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

Comment: 12-15 12:46:18.172: E/AndroidRuntime(2076): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{logic.jobin.touristguide/logic.jobin.touristguide.PointOfInterest}: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-15 12:46:18.172: E/AndroidRuntime(2076):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2585)
12-15 12:46:18.172: E/AndroidRuntime(2076):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
12-15 12:46:18.172: E/AndroidRuntime(2076):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)

Comment: 12-15 12:46:18.172: E/AndroidRuntime(2076):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
12-15 12:46:18.172: E/AndroidRuntime(2076):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-15 12:46:18.172: E/AndroidRuntime(2076):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
12-15 12:46:18.172: E/AndroidRuntime(2076):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
12-15 12:46:18.172: E/AndroidRuntime(2076):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

Comment: 12-15 12:46:18.172: E/AndroidRuntime(2076):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
12-15 12:46:18.172: E/AndroidRuntime(2076):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
12-15 12:46:18.172: E/AndroidRuntime(2076):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
12-15 12:46:18.172: E/AndroidRuntime(2076):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-15 12:46:18.172: E/AndroidRuntime(2076): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: please post the declaration part of videoId.And please post the LogCat error

Comment: 12-15 12:46:18.172: E/AndroidRuntime(2076):  at logic.jobin.touristguide.PointOfInterest.<init>(PointOfInterest.java:14)
12-15 12:46:18.172: E/AndroidRuntime(2076):  at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
12-15 12:46:18.172: E/AndroidRuntime(2076):  at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1429)
12-15 12:46:18.172: E/AndroidRuntime(2076):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
12-15 12:46:18.172: E/AndroidRuntime(2076):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2577)12-15 12:46:18.172: E/AndroidRuntime(2076):... 11 more

Comment: its hard to read.. please edit your post and show it in your post

Comment: Where have you set the value of videoId?

Comment: It's now working with Raghav's code given below. Thank you very much for trying.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Intent intent=new Intent(this,secondclass.class);
intent.putExtra("videoId",videoId);
startActivity(intent);
```

and in your second class try 2 get these items by doing

```
  Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if(extras!=null){
            String videoId=extras.getString("videoId");

        }
```

just after u define your class i hope dis would help u out 2 get the values on other page

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you are getting the same type, for example, if you put a String, get a String.
Then try with:

```
getIntent().getStringExtra("videoId");
```

Comment: I got it with the above code from Raghav. Thank you very much for trying.